# Ruby on Rails issues on windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, rubygems

I have been trying for hours to get Ruby on Rails working on my Windows 7 computer. I have installed Ruby, Rails and mySQL. I am following the tutorial from Lynda.com but every time I try to create a new project I get a whole host of errors... Below is the result of my trying to create a new project. Any help will be VERY MUCH appreciated.

```
     C:\Users\Zack\Rails>rails new sample
          create  
          create  README.rdoc
          create  Rakefile
          create  config.ru
          create  .gitignore
          create  Gemfile
          create  app
          create  app/assets/images/rails.png
          create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
          create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
          create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
          create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
          create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
          create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
          create  app/models/.gitkeep
          create  config
          create  config/routes.rb
          create  config/application.rb
          create  config/environment.rb
          create  config/environments
          create  config/environments/development.rb
          create  config/environments/production.rb
          create  config/environments/test.rb
          create  config/initializers
          create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
          create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
          create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
          create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
          create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
          create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
          create  config/locales
          create  config/locales/en.yml
          create  config/boot.rb
          create  config/database.yml
          create  db
          create  db/seeds.rb
          create  doc
          create  doc/README_FOR_APP
          create  lib
          create  lib/tasks
          create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
          create  lib/assets
          create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
          create  log
          create  log/.gitkeep
          create  public
          create  public/404.html
          create  public/422.html
          create  public/500.html
          create  public/favicon.ico
          create  public/index.html
          create  public/robots.txt
          create  script
          create  script/rails
          create  test/fixtures
          create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
          create  test/functional
          create  test/functional/.gitkeep
          create  test/integration
          create  test/integration/.gitkeep
          create  test/unit
          create  test/unit/.gitkeep
          create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
          create  test/test_helper.rb
          create  tmp/cache
          create  tmp/cache/assets
          create  vendor/assets/javascripts
          create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
          create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
          create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
          create  vendor/plugins
          create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
             run  bundle install
            Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
            troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!

C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:305:in `read': Is a directory - C:/ProgramData/gemrc (Errno::EISDIR)
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:305:in `load_file'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:200:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:319:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:319:in `configuration'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler rubygems_integration.rb:34:in`configuration'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundlerrubygems_integration.rb:53:in'sources='
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/source rubygems.rb:249:in `ensure in remote_specs'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:249:in `remote_specs'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:162:in `fetch_specs'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:66:in `specs'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in`block (2 levels) in index'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in`each'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in`block in index'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in`index'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in`resolve'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in`specs'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:109:in`resolve_remotely!'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:247:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:2
7:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocatio
n.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in
 `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:4
34:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <main>
'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:4:
in `with_friendly_errors'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/bin/bundle:20:in `<main>'

C:\Users\Zack\Rails>
```

Comment: Quickly, thinking ur using the latest version of Ruby. Try playing with 1.9 version. 2.0 version was released recently (may be a week ago). But you have lot of help for 1.9 version. Cheers.

Comment: Ruby2.0 was released yesterday. There were also [problems reported running bundler](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubyinstaller/mg5ailNICvM/cHctJk4ZNJIJ) on Ruby2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be an answer as such, and I don't want it to come across as snarky or anything, but you would be doing yourself a favor by looking into [VirtualBox(free)](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and installing an instance of [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) or another *nix operating system.  Whether you're doing this for fun or for profit, you will spend a lot less time trying to figure out why you're getting errors and more time coding if you use something other than Windows to work with Ruby and Rails.  It just works better.

I started from scratch with Rails 3 years ago and this is probably one of the best steps I took to become a better developer.

Comment: You can even use Vagrant (http://www.vagrantup.com/) to easily create/manage your development environments. I agree with Ryan. Rails on windows can be a pain.

Comment: I'll jump in and agree as well, Rails on Windows just isn't as well worked out as it is on Linux and OS X.

Comment: Well it sounds like the consensus is to just nix using Windows. Thanks guys! I appreciate it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try Rails Installer. I have no issues with my rails. Easy one-click install. [www.railsinstaller.org](http://railsinstaller.org)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try the virtual box solution but might give this a try as well.